# Connecting Multiple Storyboards in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

I am in the process of building an iOS app using Swift and have been advised to use a storyboard for each feature as each feature will have about 10 views. Starting from the main storyboard, could anyone provide advice on how to transition between storyboards using Swift? Alternatively, is there something better to do than using multiple storyboards if I want to avoid the confusion of a 50+ view main storyboard?

Here is what ended up working:

```
let secondVC:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "SecondStoryboard", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("numberTwo") as UIViewController

@IBAction func changeStoryBoardButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        presentViewController(secondVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your app needs to move to a new controller that's in a different storyboard, you have to instantiate the new storyboard, then instantiate the initial view controller there.

```c
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "SomeStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc2 = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController // or whatever the class is of that initial vc
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much. I tried:

let secondSB : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SecondStoryboard.storyboard", bundle: nil)
    
let secondVC = secondSB!.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController
    
@IBAction func changeStoryBoardButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        presentViewController(secondVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

Getting an error that UIViewController doesn't have member secondSB /secondVC. Researched that issue but didn't manage to resolve.
And does my function to change the storyboard make sense?

Comment: @iOSBeginner You shouldn't have the .storyboard on the name (though it may not matter). You need to edit your question to show the complete code inside whatever methods you put them. I think you're having a problem with scope -- secondVC and secondSB are both local variables I think, but it would help to see the code in its context.